# Jest-Puppeteer > Trying to get textContent of last h4 on page

Tags: javascript, dom, jestjs, jest-puppeteer

I am trying to get the textContent of the last h4 on a page.
Following is my code snippet.
when I console.log models.length it is 0. There are actually 39 h4s on the page.

Please advise

```
    page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })
    let models = [];
    models = await page.evaluate(() => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('h4'), e => e.textContent));

    const numModels = models.length;
    const fileName = models[numModels - 1];

``
```

Comment: I tried this. Also did not work ```
    const fileName = await page.waitForSelector('h4:last-of-type').textContent;```

Comment: i think its better to use innerText, I don't think textContent will work

Answer (score 1):

This finally worked.

```js
const h4All = await page.$$('h4');
const h4Count = h4All.length;
const fileName = h4All[h4Count - 1];
```

Comment: Yes this is the solution. I saw you posted many questions related with scrap. May be i can help you in those part. Contact me if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my side this works

```
const result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    let score = document.querySelector('#tableInfo50 > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > 
                 td.text-left.bold-text').innerText
    return {
         score
    }
})
```

Comment: I want the last h4. textContent. I don’t know in advance how may h4s there are. Also h4 are in a long chain of divs

Comment: This is the selector of the 14th element in Google dev tools. #underline-company > div > div > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > div > div > h4  As I said I don't want the 14th, I want the last. In dev-tools $('#underline-company > div > div > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > div > div > h4').innerText yields undefined.

Comment: This works as jquery selector in dev-tools $('#underline-company > div > div > div > div:nth-child(14) > div > div > div > h4').html() ---But how do I get last one,

Comment: Hi Steven, this is weekend. If you have skype lets talk there. I will take care and try to solve via team viewer

Comment: Hi iGuru, Thanks for the offer. I came up with an answer which I will post below.